# Expected Type Before / After —>, Expected Declaration in Swift 3

Tags: ios, token, stripe-payments, swift3, completionhandler

So, I created a typealias to store a completion handler, to later pass into a function called submitTokenToBackend using Stripe's iOS library. Here is my code:

```
// MARK: - Create Completion Handlers

typealias CompletionHandler = (_ token: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void

// MARK: - Submit Token To Backend

func submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

}

// MARK: - STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate


func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
    print("Card number: \(textField.cardParams.number) Exp Month: \(textField.cardParams.expMonth) Exp Year: \(textField.cardParams.expYear) CVC: \(textField.cardParams.cvc)")
    self.buyButton.isEnabled = textField.isValid
}

// MARK: Initialize Card Params

let cardParams = STPCardParams()

func cardParamsFunc() {
    cardParams.number = "4242424242424242"
    cardParams.expMonth = 10
    cardParams.expYear = 2018
    cardParams.cvc = "123"
    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams){ (token, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        } else if let token = token {

// HERE'S WHERE I'M GETTING ERRORS

            self.submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler: CompletionHandler) -> Void {
                if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Show receipt page")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting these weird errors, now, in Swift 3 concerning my completion handler not having expected types. Not an isolated incident, either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler: CompletionHandler) -> Void {
```

This is a declaration, not a method call. You can't pass a typealias as a parameter. And `-> Void` does not make sense here at all. You almost certainly meant

```
self.submitTokenToBackend {
```

If you have further questions on this, however, you need to provide code we can compile (see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and list the exact errors. "Weird errors" is not particularly helpful for debugging.

Comment: Hi Rob. The submitTokenToBackend function with completion handler takes an argument of Completion Handler, the typealias declared earlier **typealias CompletionHandler = (_ token: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void** What am I supposed to pass in if not the Completion Handler? The arguments of the typealias? Wouldn't that defeat the point?

Comment: Just doing **self.submitTokenToBackend {** raises the exception **Contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored** with a fix of **_,_ in** which raises the errors **Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";"** and **Expected expression**

Answer (score 2):

Almost all thing you need is described in Rob Napier's answer.

I'll try to show you a little more concrete code...

You can define the completion handler and pass it to `submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler:)` like this:

```
            let theCompletionHandler: CompletionHandler = {token, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Show receipt page")
                }
            }
            self.submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler: theCompletionHandler)
```

With removing intermediate let-constant, you can write it in this way:

```
            self.submitTokenToBackend(completionHandler: {token, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Show receipt page")
                }
            })
```

Using the trailing closure feature of Swift, the above code can be shortened to:

```
            self.submitTokenToBackend {token, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Show receipt page")
                }
            }
```

Your code is far from any of above three.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but... Where is 'CompletionHandler' implementation? As I understand, you just declarate some like block in Objective - C ('typedef void (^completionHandler)(id token);'), but don't use it.

Comment: @OOper Yep. I was just about to accept Rob Napier's answer. I didn't do anything with the handler and figured it out "on my own" after understanding that I declared the handler without passing anything in. Not sure if I said that correctly, but used a trailing closure and I got it working! Thanks, everyone!